# How to UNION results and reformat in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents like this:

```
{
    "si" : "10.131.6.79",
    "sp" : 36158,
    "n" : "snat",
    "tsi" : "194.230.159.203",
    "tsp" : 36158,
    "di" : "205.185.208.165",
    "dp" : 443
}
{
    "si" : "10.128.103.115",
    "sp" : 56261,
    "n" : "dnat",
    "tdi" : "194.230.159.107",
    "tdp" : 56261,
    "di" : "8.253.207.243",
    "dp" : 443
}
```

And I like to query which concatenates result of several matches. Desired result is

```
{
    "sourceIp" : "10.131.6.79",
    "sourcePort" : 36158,
    "trandisp" : "snat",
    "sourceNatIp" : "194.230.159.203",
    "sourceNatPort" : 36158,
    "destIp" : "205.185.208.165",
    "dp" : 443
}
{
    "sourceIp" : "10.128.103.115",
    "sourcePort" : 56261,
    "trandisp" : "dnat",
    "destinationNatIp" : "194.230.159.107",
    "destinationNatPort" : 56261,
    "destIp" : "8.253.207.243",
    "destPort" : 443
}
```

In principle I managed it with this command:

```
{ $concatArrays: [ 
db.sessions.aggregate([
    {$match:{n:"snat"}},
    {$project : {
      _id : 0,sourceIp : "$si",sourcePort : "$sp",sourceNatIp : "$tsi",sourceNatPort : "$tsp", destIp : "$di",destPort : "$dp", trandisp: "$n"
    }}
  ]),
db.sessions.aggregate([
    {$match:{n:"dnat"}},
    {$project : {
      _id : 0,sourceIp : "$si",sourcePort : "$sp",destinationNatIp : "$tdi",destinationNatPort : "$tdp", destIp : "$di",destPort : "$dp" ,trandisp: "$n"
    }}
  ])
 ] }
```

But I need it as query result, i.e. I like to create a view.

In SQL I would write

```
select 
    si as SourceIp, sp as SourcePort, n as transdisp, 
    tsi as SourceNatIp, tsp as SouceNatPort, 
    null as DestinationNatIp, null as DestinationNatPort
from sessions
where n = 'snat'
union all
select 
    si as SourceIp, sp as SourcePort, n as transdisp, 
    null as SourceNatIp, null as SouceNatPort, 
    tdi as DestinationNatIp, tdp as DestinationNatPort
from sessions
where n = 'dnat';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to take a look at [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) operator which allows you to run mutliple separate queries and get results as single document. Then you can run [$concatArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/index.html), [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) and [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to combine and promote your query results.

```
db.sessions.aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            q1: [
                { $match:{n:"snat"} },
                { $project : {
                _id : 0,sourceIp : "$si",sourcePort : "$sp",sourceNatIp : "$tsi",sourceNatPort : "$tsp", destIp : "$di",destPort : "$dp", trandisp: "$n"
                }}
            ],
            q2: [
                { $match:{n:"dnat"}},
                { $project : {
                _id : 0,sourceIp : "$si",sourcePort : "$sp",destinationNatIp : "$tdi",destinationNatPort : "$tdp", destIp : "$di",destPort : "$dp" ,trandisp: "$n"
                }}
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            all: {
                $concatArrays: [ "$q1", "$q2" ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$all"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$all"
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pKiwms5Vs7U)

Comment: Thank you it works. But I cannot use it because I wanted to create a view. Looks like MongoDB does not utilize indexes in views, however index usage is vital as my database will get app. 500 billion documents.